# How to implement a job queue in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, job-queue

There are a couple of API requests in my React Native project where, if the device has no connection at the time of the request, the request should be tried again in the background once the connection is back up.

All the React Native libraries I have found for this are old and unmaintained (react-native-queue and react-native-background-task). Does anybody know how to implement this? And since it is only required for it to work on Android, can this be done using Headless JS?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm looking for a solution but only see react-native-queue and react-native-job-queue which are poorly maintained